# Apply a function for each element of vector c++. But this function should also be a function of indices of that element

Tags: c++

Consider vector<int> C

I aim to calculate sum i*C[i] using some stl library. Is there any STL function there to do that?

Comment: The algorithms available to you are listed on [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

Comment: I downvoted because this does not show any research effort and the downvote button recommends downvoting posts that do now show any research effort. A quick search in your favorite search engine will provide you many related posts for the problem.

Comment: @Atmo `std::accumulate` is probably what the OP is looking for, but it's in the `<numeric>` header.

Comment: You need to do extra work to find the index of an item with an algorithm. If you need the index, you're *usually* best off just using a counted loop.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: `std::accumulate` is listed on the page I linked (it is around the bottom of the page). TBH, I never spent time checking *absolutely everything* was there but I must say this question was not really enticing me to spend more time on it than checking that the page lists `for_each`, `transform` and `accumulate` and that is probably all that is needed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::accumulate` is all you need. Just remember to reset `index` to 0 each time you run `std::accumulate`

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{ 1,2,1 };
    int index{};
    int result = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, [&index](int a, int b) {
        return a + b * index++;
        });
    std::cout << result << '\n';
}
```

Alternately, it can all be done on one line by using the comma operator. This eliminates the extra indexing variable by dual purposing the result variable.

```
int s = (s=0, std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, [&s](int a, int b) {return a + b * s++;}));
```

Comment: *Just remember to reset index to 0 each time you run std::accumulate* -- Or you can create a function that has `index` as a local variable that is initialized to 0.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yep, or use the comma operator.